# Rails redirect to the post after a comment is made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a comment form on my tickets show page. I can fill it out, but when submitting the comment, it goes to the comments show page. I need this to just go back to the ticket it was showing.

I have this code at the moment:

comment_controller.rb

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @comment.save
      format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and a similar thing with the destroy method

```
def destroy
  @comment.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to comments_path, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to get it to remember which ticket it was on, for it to redirect to.

I have entered the associations with the models with ticket.rb and comments.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace the

```
redirect_to comments_path
```

with

```
redirect_to :back
# or 
redirect_to(:back)
```

which after the comment is made, it returns to the previous page

If you're using rails 5, use

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```

instead

Comment: Perfect mate, got it.